# How can I access process node data sheets?

Tags: datasheet, asic

I am searching for process node data sheets. Specifically, I'm interested in TSMC's 16nm, 12nm, 10nm, 7nm nodes, as well as Samsung's 14nm, 10nm nodes. I did not find anything with Google.

How can I access process node data sheets?

Comment: Perhaps you might explain what "process node data sheets" are for?

Comment: I mean general documentation pertaining to a process technology. I want to compare, for example, TSMC's 16nm node with Samsung's 12nm node. Standard cell library databooks would be a good example of documentation I'm after. As an example, here is the databook for TSMC's 180nm node. http://www.utdallas.edu/~mxl095420/EE6306/Final%20project/tsmc18_component.pdf

Comment: Step 1: Call your local TSMC or Samsung salesperson. Step 2: Convince them you are legitimately interested in and have the financial capability to design and fabricate a design on their process. Step 3: Ask for the design kit.

Comment: @Randomblue, that doesn't look like TSMC documentation. It looks like documentation for a cell library offered by a 3rd-party IP vendor.